# A javascript class with an array is static

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm using coffeescript to create the following class:

```
class User
  userId: 0
  rooms: new Array()
```

When I create a new instance of the class and add something to the array, any new instance also contains the same array. The generated javascript is:

```
  var User;

  User = (function() {

    User.name = 'User';

    function User() {}

    User.prototype.userId = 0;

    User.prototype.rooms = new Array();

    return User;

  })();
```

How do I design the class that has a new empty array every time I instantiate the class?

Comment: `User.prototype.room = new Array()`, the `prototype` keyword here means that all of the `User` objects share this field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `userId` and `rooms` to be on `this`, not on the prototype, or else all instances will share them.

```
class User
  constructor: (@userId = 0, @rooms = []) ->

u = new User 1, [1,2]
u2 = new User 2, [3,4]

alert "#{ u.userId } #{ u.rooms } #{u2.userId} #{u2.rooms}"
```

[Try it here](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3aclass%20User%0A%20%20constructor%3a%20%28@userId%20=%200,%20@rooms%20=%20%5B%5D%29%20-%3E%0A%0Au%20=%20new%20User%201,%20%5B1,2%5D%0Au2%20=%20new%20User%202,%20%5B3,4%5D%0A%0Aalert%20%22#%7B%20u.userId%20%7D%20#%7B%20u.rooms%20%7D%20#%7Bu2.userId%7D%20#%7Bu2.rooms%7D%22).

The `@` simply means `this.`.

The constructor line does a lot.  It defines a constructor that

1) sets the passed values as `userId` and `rooms` on the object (not the prototype)
2) gives a default value for each property if they are not provided.

Note I didn't even have to do anything else in the constructor.  Definitely follow the link so you can see the javascript this example creates.